# How to secure LED MR16 bulbs that fall out of fixture

Tags: lighting, led

I'm replacing my halogen MR16 bulbs with LED bulbs from Gledopto. The bases are GU5.3, so they are the "bi-pin" model that simply push into the socket, without any twisting to help secure them.

The fixture is a 3-pendant thing, where the open sockets face downward. My problem is that my new MR16 GU5.3 LED lamps (bulbs) are heavier than my previous halogen lamps--in fact, just heavy enough that they are prone to falling out of 2 of the 3 sockets. I'll see if I can upload an image, in case that provides any insight. The new LED bulb is on the right, and the old halogen is on the left. Even the socket where the LED remains in place feels awfully ready to just drop the thing out.

[image: 2 pendants with different bulbs]
(For a while, I thought these new bulbs might be GZ5.3 instead of GU5.3, but a Gledopto rep confirmed that they're proper GU5.3.)

Any advice on how I can keep these bad-boys from falling out? Maybe a cleverly hidden strip of electrical tape or a dollop of silicone caulking? Perhaps slightly flaring the pins? Or let me know if you have any warnings like, "Good lord, man--don't use tape! It'll melt!"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you verify the socket type? Easiest would be to upload a picture showing all writing on the old halogen bulb plus a measurement (picture next to a tape measure will do) of the pins.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly flaring the pins will probably do the trick, but...

I am a bit skeptical about the quality of Gledopto. No personal experience, but the stuff I have found so far pretty clear does *not* have UL or ETL or similar listing and that, combined with the mechanical problems you're experiencing (points to poor quality control and/or poor design), weight & size (seems "big" but hard to tell from the picture) makes me a bit suspicious.

I recommend looking at a better quality manufacturer. A typical example is CREE (no personal connection, just highly recommended based on many sources) but there are plenty of others. In addition to UL or ETL listing, look for a long warranty (e.g., 5 years) or DLC certification as a further indication of quality.

Before you order anything, measure the bulbs you have now to determine the right size. You have a nice fixture and ruin the look by having the new bulb stick out an inch. Any quality manufacturer will have spec. sheets available showing the exact dimensions.

Comment: Agree on ugliness of your new bulbs.  There are MR16 LED bulbs that are the same size as your old ones.  Not worth a whole new answer to say this but there are ones that are all glass or the plastic back has a metallic silver color instead of white plastic.  Those will look better.

Comment: Yep, the Gledopto is kind of hideous. I hadn't checked the size before ordering it, so that's on me. I'm actually looking to get a bulb that can do color, and that works on a zigbee network. I just bought a Philips Hue bridge, but Philips doesn't make a GU5.3 bulb. In fact, I'm having a devil of a time finding *any* zigbee-capable GU5.3 bulb. For instance, I checked out CREE, but no joy. If anyone has recommendations on that front, I'd appreciate that as well.

Comment: Are you 110% sure the socket actually is 5.3?  If it wasn't that would explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem.  If the light pins aren't making good *physical* contact, that means they're also not making good *electrical* contact.

And *electrical* contact is a deal-breaker, because that will lead to serious ***arc faults***.

So, no.

You already have halogen lights that do fit properly, so you know the fixture is not defective.

That leaves the new LED bulbs. Either you have a misunderstanding about the size, or the new bulbs are not manufactured to spec.

I note that while Gledopto does have its own web site (which doesn't load for me)... I also see that the top 10 search results for "Gledopto" are rounded out by Amazon.com and **AliExpress**.

This is the mark of cheap junk.

Amazon.com has a program called "Amazon Marketplace" where **third-party listings (effectively eBay) are blended with bona-fide Amazon product listings.  It is difficult to tell them apart. Amazon also gives them access to its warehousing and shipping system, which means these third-party items ship with Prime. Those items are generally bought wholesale off Alibaba for pennies on the dollar.

AliExpress, of course, is Alibaba's *own* site offering individual sale of Alibaba crud.

All of it is cheap and dangerous junk, with faked safety marks, and has not had any bona-fide testing by an independent testing lab, as is required for the North American Market (NEC 110.2). A competent mark would be UL, CSA or ETL.  This involves a variety of testing, from components not catching fire to the plastic being borated to not be a *fire accelerant*.  Safety costs money.  They are, of course, absent from your lights.

The marks you do see are CE (there's no penalty for faking it outside the EU), FCC and RoHS which have nothing to do with safety.  They stick those on *everything*.

So the answer is, "Back to Amazon it goes for being cheap junk that is not UL Listed".

Comment: Thanks! Yep, as I mention in my above reply, I'd be happy if anyone has recommendations for color-capable zigbee-enabled GU5.3-base bulbs. 

There are several manufacturers listed on Amazon, but they all have the same characteristics that you rightly notice of Gledopto. That is, it seems like they're all cruddy manufacturers out of China.

Comment: We don't do product recommendations here, but I note everyone raving about Gledopto said the same thing: they're like Philips Hue *but cheaper*.  So that seems like an obvious recommendation.

Comment: It all comes down to $. It costs $ to design, $ to build (higher quality components) and $$ to list/certify for safety. The design & certification costs get amortized over everything produced. For a mass-market product, no problem - and then the difference in price is just the difference in components. But for a niche market like: "color" (much smaller than plain white light) + "zigbee" (definitely a small part of the market) + "GU5.3" (much smaller than Edison base), the volume production just isn't enough to lower the price of the quality stuff to an affordable level.

Comment: If they had a good working relationship with UL, that wouldn't be a problem. The engineers would know how to design for UL, the right feedstocks from the right vendors would already be coming into the factory, the UL inspectors are already on-site, etc.   UL would be like "OK you're putting a Gu5.3 base on that bulb we already listed, yeah we see what you're doing there". The incremental cost would be low.  The problem is the Great Leap from crud-making to that.